# Leaflet id properties

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I assign id tags to leaflet polylines so that I can show/hide or do other operations on them later? 
I'll have around 100+ polylines. Is there a way I can set an id property to it?

Also I noticed the leaflet module has a leaflet-src.js file in it. Can I add the property to the L.Polyline using this.ident and add it while constructing the polyline in the html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new `L.Polyline`, you can add a `id` key to the `options` hash which you can then operate on/inspect later while looping through the `featureGroup` or other more vanilla JavaScript grouping that contains it.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-l.polyline